# Trouble running converted custom trained model on RPI4 using TFLite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4, darknet, roboflow

I am trying to run a mask detecting model on my RPI4.

I followed this Roboflow tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXLLNa4IrmM&list=LL&index=1&t=1169s.

However, after converting the darknet model to a TFLite model, I am getting this error:

> 2021-01-30 21:42:03.351149: E
> tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132]
> HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "TFLite_detection_webcam.py", line 138, in 
> interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_CKPT)   File
> "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter.py",
> line 207, in **init**    model_path, self._custom_op_registerers))
> ValueError: Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'RESIZE_BILINEAR'
> version '3' Registration    failed.

I know I am probably missing information that could help solve this problem, but I am not sure what else I should be including.

I was able to run premade object models, however the custom model I made using the YouTube guide did not work.

How do I solve this issue? Or, is there another way to train a custom model to work on the RPI4?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a too old version of Tensorflow. Can you try the latest version of nightly?